# windows 10 determine if "maintain aspect ratio" is set on a PCs GPU

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am trying to programically determine if a video card is set to "maintain aspect ratio". I've tracked down this registry key in windows.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\\00\00
scaling =

- 4 = maintain aspect ratio 3 = scale full screen 2 = center image

This would be great, but it appears that "maintain display scaling" will retain whatever that key was set to before.

Does anyone have another location or another method to confirm, that a video card is set to maintain aspect ratio? (not using a cards GUI)

I should clarify this isn't about DPI settings, this is about aspect ratio of the video being displayed.

Comment: Not even sure this is a GPU thing.  When I'm using VLC to play videos, VLC knows if the aspect ratio is locked or not, not my GPU.  And I can set two different videos in two different VLC windows one with maintain and the other without.  If I'm querying the registry, how would it know which video I was looking for?

Comment: The ability to set this is in most modern graphic card's GUI, For example Intel integrated cards would be launch the integrated graphic settings > General settings > scaling > set center image or maintain aspect ratio. If not the registry I'm open to any scripting option.

Comment: You are correct in saying that these scaling options do in fact exist in the graphics driver.  I verified in my laptop's Intel HD Graphics Control Panel.  At that point, it would most likely be a registry setting.  I'm interested to see what kind of answers you get.

Comment: I found this script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515#content It modifies the user32.dll and by default sets it to maintain aspect ratio which is what I want. I haven't decided this is the answer but its a interesting avenue.

Comment: I keep saying modifies, but I guess its more accurate to say calls the user32.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer (even though it's not) since I need to space to show what I've done so far--in case it helps anyone towards the answer.  I'm currently looking through other Windows API libs to try and find the answer.

@MinerBob, I saw that guy's code yesterday too but couldn't get it to work so I changed a few things and am now reporting the data as correctly as I can but looking over the struct, it doesn't appear to contain the information you're after but here's how you can generate the output to review it yourself:

```
Add-Type "
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DEVMODE
{
    private const int CCHDEVICENAME = 0x20;
    private const int CCHFORMNAME = 0x20;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public short dmSpecVersion;
    public short dmDriverVersion;
    public short dmSize;
    public short dmDriverExtra;
    public int dmFields;
    public int dmPositionX;
    public int dmPositionY;
    public ScreenOrientation dmDisplayOrientation;
    public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;
    public short dmColor;
    public short dmDuplex;
    public short dmYResolution;
    public short dmTTOption;
    public short dmCollate;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
    public string dmFormName;
    public short dmLogPixels;
    public int dmBitsPerPel;
    public int dmPelsWidth;
    public int dmPelsHeight;
    public int dmDisplayFlags;
    public int dmDisplayFrequency;
    public int dmICMMethod;
    public int dmICMIntent;
    public int dmMediaType;
    public int dmDitherType;
    public int dmReserved1;
    public int dmReserved2;
    public int dmPanningWidth;
    public int dmPanningHeight;
}

public static class user32
{

    [DllImport(`"user32.dll`")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODE lpDevMode);

    public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
    public const int ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS = -2;

    public static void GetDisplaySettings()
    {  
        DEVMODE vDevMode = new DEVMODE();

        if (EnumDisplaySettings(null, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref vDevMode)) 
        {
        Console.WriteLine(@`"
            dmDeviceName = {0} 
            dmSpecVersion = {1} 
            dmDriverVersion = {2} 
            dmSize = {3} 
            dmDriverExtra = {4} 
            dmFields = {5} 
            dmPositionX = {6} 
            dmPositionY = {7} 
            dmDisplayOrientation = {8} 
            dmDisplayFixedOutput = {9} 
            dmColor = {10} 
            dmDuplex = {11} 
            dmYResolution = {12} 
            dmTTOption = {13} 
            dmCollate = {14} 
            dmFormName = {15} 
            dmLogPixels = {16} 
            dmBitsPerPel = {17} 
            dmPelsWidth = {18} 
            dmPelsHeight = {19} 
            dmDisplayFlags = {20} 
            dmDisplayFrequency = {21} 
            dmICMMethod = {22} 
            dmICMIntent = {23} 
            dmMediaType = {24} 
            dmDitherType = {25} 
            dmReserved1 = {26} 
            dmReserved2 = {27} 
            dmPanningWidth = {28} 
            dmPanningHeight = {29}
        `",
            vDevMode.dmDeviceName, 
            vDevMode.dmSpecVersion, 
            vDevMode.dmDriverVersion, 
            vDevMode.dmSize, 
            vDevMode.dmDriverExtra, 
            vDevMode.dmFields, 
            vDevMode.dmPositionX, 
            vDevMode.dmPositionY, 
            vDevMode.dmDisplayOrientation, 
            vDevMode.dmDisplayFixedOutput, 
            vDevMode.dmColor, 
            vDevMode.dmDuplex, 
            vDevMode.dmYResolution, 
            vDevMode.dmTTOption, 
            vDevMode.dmCollate, 
            vDevMode.dmFormName, 
            vDevMode.dmLogPixels, 
            vDevMode.dmBitsPerPel, 
            vDevMode.dmPelsWidth, 
            vDevMode.dmPelsHeight, 
            vDevMode.dmDisplayFlags, 
            vDevMode.dmDisplayFrequency, 
            vDevMode.dmICMMethod, 
            vDevMode.dmICMIntent, 
            vDevMode.dmMediaType, 
            vDevMode.dmDitherType, 
            vDevMode.dmReserved1, 
            vDevMode.dmReserved2, 
            vDevMode.dmPanningWidth, 
            vDevMode.dmPanningHeight
        );
        }
    }
}
" -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms

[user32]::GetDisplaySettings()
```

**UPDATE 1**:

According to the MSDN documentation for EnumDisplaySettings:

> The EnumDisplaySettings function sets values for the following five
>   DEVMODE members:
>
> ```
> dmBitsPerPel
> dmPelsWidth
> dmPelsHeight
> dmDisplayFlags
> dmDisplayFrequency
> ```

what I was originally focusing on 'dmScale' appears to be specific to Printers--as in, only Printer functions that populate the DEVMODE struct will fill that field.

**Update 2:**

It appears everything under GraphicsDrivers key, well, is updated by the graphics driver that's loaded for that monitor.  Very Intuitive.  Every article I could find talks about either changing the value in the vendor-specific UI that interacts with its driver OR using the appropriate monitor key under Graphics Drivers to interact with this feature.

There must be some Windows Graphics Driver documentation that talks about each driver updating/honoring these values.  Looking for that now to confirm.

**Update 3:**

Updated source to include the DEVMODE structure signature from pinvoke.net.  Also, I believe I found the smoking gun in Windows driver documentation:

> Scaling depends on the source and target modes that are used for a
>   path. In addition, the caller can call SetDisplayConfig without
>   specifying the target mode information (that is, setting the
>   modeInfoArray parameter is optional and can be set to NULL).
>   Therefore, the caller cannot typically predict if SetDisplayConfig
>   must perform any scaling. **Furthermore, no API exists to get the full
>   list of scaling types that the graphics adapter supports. The
>   EnumDisplaySettings Win32 function (described in the Windows SDK
>   documentation) returns DMDFO_DEFAULT in the dmDisplayFixedOutput
>   member of the DEVMODE structure that the lpDevMode parameter points to
>   when the caller requests the new Windows 7 scaling types.**
>
> The scaling that a caller passes to SetDisplayConfig is a scaling
>   intent rather than an explicit request to perform a scaling operation.
>   If scaling is required (for example, source and target resolutions
>   differ), SetDisplayConfig uses the scaling that the caller supplies.
>   If the supplied scaling is not supported, SetDisplayConfig uses the
>   graphics adapter's default scaling. When the source and target
>   resolutions that the caller passes to SetDisplayConfig are the same,
>   SetDisplayConfig always sets identify scaling.

...my bolded emphasis. DMDFO_DEFAULT, according to the header file, is 0.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/scaling-the-desktop-image
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea